# Add object to variable defined for form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

I have a form that uses `$scope.booking` variable composed of several fields and array, all loaded from HTML.
I need to add an array of object from javascript, adding one object per time.
I tryed

```
$scope.booking.newExternalUsers[$scope.count]= $scope.user.newExternalUser;
```

and

```
$scope.booking.newExternalUsers.push=$scope.user.newExternalUser;
```

but I receive `Cannot set property '0' of undefined` and `Cannot set property of undefined`, it is correct because I have instantiated only `$scope.booking={}`
Maybe is a stupid question, but I am almost new in angularjs, how can I add the `$scope.user.newExternalUser` one pertime (for each button event)?.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define the property `newExternalUsers` in `booking` array first

```
$scope.booking={
  'newExternalUsers' : []
}
```

or

```
$scope.booking.newExternalUsers=[]
```

Then push the item to an `booking` array

```
$scope.booking.newExternalUsers.push($scope.user.newExternalUser);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define the array first before set values to it.

like this:

```js
$scope.booking = {};

$scope.booking.newExternalUsers = [];
```

or

```js
$scope.booking = {
    newExternalUsers: []
};
```

**Then**

You can add items to it as you want, like this:

`$scope.booking.newExternalUsers[$scope.count]= $scope.user.newExternalUser;`

or using [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

`$scope.booking.newExternalUsers.push($scope.user.newExternalUser);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate `$scope.booking.newExternalUsers=[]`

Comment: it creates a different object

Comment: @luca You have to define `newExternalUsers` as an Array first, before you can use it. The `undefined` error is because your `$scope.booking` object doesn't have the `newExternalUsers` property defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have a controller. In that controller you can have this:

```
$onInit() {
  this.booking = { newExternaUsers: [] };
}
```

Then it's initiated once when the controller starts.